Getting linking error for VTK library in Qt C++ after install and setup on my Windows 10
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN31vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanupD1Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN20vtkDebugLeaksManagerD1Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN6vtksys18SystemToolsManagerD1Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1ab): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN11vtkRenderer3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseC2EP13vtkObjectBaseRKNS_11NoReferenceE'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN15vtkRenderWindow3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x201): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN25vtkRenderWindowInteractor3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x22f): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN25vtkRenderWindowInteractor15SetRenderWindowEP15vtkRenderWindow'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x235): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9vtkPoints3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3bc): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN12vtkCellArray3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x408): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x422): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN7vtkLine3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4da): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN11vtkPolyData3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x51f): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN11vtkPolyData8SetLinesEP12vtkCellArray'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x525): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN17vtkPolyDataMapper3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x551): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN17vtkPolyDataMapper12SetInputDataEP11vtkPolyData'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x557): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8vtkActor3NewEv'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x599): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN11vtkRenderer8AddActorEP7vtkProp'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x69c): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6f4): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x700): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x70c): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x718): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN19vtkSmartPointerBaseD2Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN6vtksys18SystemToolsManagerC1Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3e): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN20vtkDebugLeaksManagerC1Ev'
:-1: error: release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x57): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN31vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanupC1Ev'
:-1: error: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
:-1: error: [Makefile.Release:72: release/test.exe] Error 1

#.pro file
QT       += core gui
#QT       += vtk
QT       += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\Program Files\\VTK\\include\\vtk-9.3\\"

LIBS += -LC:\VTK-9.3.0\build\bin\Release

#INSTALLPATH += C:/"Program Files"/VTK/install/include
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\Program Files\\VTK\\include\\vtk-9.3"
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\VTK-9.3.0\\GUISupport\\Qt"
LIBS += -LC:\\"Program Files"\\VTK\\lib -lvtkCommonCore-9.3 -lvtkRenderingCore-9.3 -lvtkInteractionStyle-9.3 -lvtkRenderingOpenGL2-9.3

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

